# Regular expression to allow only specific country telephone code

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use regular expressions in php that allow only specific Afghanistan telephone code which is (+93) and after that it can accept any other number. How can I do this in php?

I have tried this expression `^(\+|00)[1-9][0-9 \-\(\)\.]{7,}$`
but I want to be able to accept `00937 878 1536` or `+937 878 1536`.

I don't know how to do this with regular expressions.

Comment: Please share your code first which you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for validation purpose, you would test this pattern :

```
^[\+ 0]0?937 \d{3} \d{4}$
```

You can test it here : https://regex101.com/r/6hVHG3/1